# Pulling data from one to many relation ship supabase

Tags: sql, flutter, dart, supabase

Currently in my app I am facing the issue of pulling the categories table, item in category table has one-to-many relationship with items from subcategory table.

This is my current code:

```
@override
  Future<Either<Exception, List<CategoryModel>>> watchAll() async {
    final ISentrySpan transaction = Sentry.startTransaction(this.runtimeType.toString(), CustomLoggerStackTrace.getCurrentStackTraceInfo(StackTrace.current));
    transaction.status = const SpanStatus.ok();
    try {
      List<Map<String, dynamic>> response = await _supabase.client.from(_categorySupabaseTable.tableName).select().order(this._categorySupabaseTable.idColumn, ascending: true).select();
      // todo some function could be created so solve these issues
      List<CategoryModel> prefabricatedCategoryModels = response.map<CategoryModel>((responseItem) {
        // maybe the cast could have been added above instead of the dynamic
        return CategoryModel.fromJson(responseItem);
      }).toList();
      // initialize list, which will include categoryModels with subcategories filled
      List<CategoryModel> completedCategoryModels = [];
      // for every questionModel fill with the options using OptionRepository
      for (CategoryModel categoryModel in prefabricatedCategoryModels) {
        Either<Exception, List<SubcategoryModel>> subcategoriesForCurrentCategory = await this._subcategoryRepository.watchAllSubcategoriesByCategoryId(categoryModel.id);
        subcategoriesForCurrentCategory.fold((Exception failure) {
          return left(failure);
        }, (List<SubcategoryModel> subcategories) {
          // has to be done this way, bcs the setter for options does not exist
          completedCategoryModels.add(categoryModel.copyWith(subcategories: subcategories));
        });
      }
      return right(completedCategoryModels);
    } on PostgrestException catch (exception) {
      log.e(exception);
      transaction.throwable = exception;
      transaction.status = const SpanStatus.internalError();
      return left(exception);
    } on Exception catch (exception) {
      // todo do something here
      log.e(exception);
      transaction.throwable = exception;
      transaction.status = const SpanStatus.internalError();
      return left(exception);
    } finally {
      await transaction.finish();
    }
  }
```

is there a way to work around this? Thanks

Comment: Is the <sql> tag really relevant? (I see no SQL above, do you expect an SQL answer? If so, add a [mcve].)

Comment: well, I think this could be fixed with calling custom made sql function in supabase, therefore I added the tag...